# Open global modal from mixin

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have created an authService mixin to call my api as logged-in user (using its token).

```
import ModalLogin from '@/components';

export default {
    components: {
        ModalLogin
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
        }
    },
    methods: { 
        authorizedGet(url) {
            if(!localStorage.getItem('user')) {
                ModalLogin.methods.show()
            } else {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In that mixin, if user is not authenticated, I'd like to open my modal login form from a component (define as a global component).

But, when it tries to do "show()", I get:

> ModalLogin is not defined

EDIT:

Here is my ModalLogin component:

```
<template>
    <!--Form modal-->
    <!-- ... -->
</template>
<script>
import User from '../models/user';

  export default {
    name: "modalLogin",
    data() {
      return {
        user: new User('', ''),
        loading: false,
        message: ''
      };
    },
    methods: {
      handleLogin() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.$validator.validateAll().then(isValid => {
            if (!isValid) {
            this.loading = false;
            return;
            }

            if (this.user.username && this.user.password) {
            this.$store.dispatch('auth/login', this.user).then(
                () => {
                this.$router.push('/profile');
                },
                error => {
                this.loading = false;
                this.message =
                    (error.response && error.response.data) ||
                    error.message ||
                    error.toString();
                }
            );
            }
        });
      },
      showModal() {
        this.$refs['login-modal'].show()
      }
    }
  }
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

...which is defined as Global as of more components:

```
// ...
import ModalLogin from '@/components/ModalLogin.vue';
// ...
/**
 * You can register global components here and use them as a plugin in your main Vue instance
 */

const GlobalComponents = {
  install(Vue) {
    // ...
    Vue.component(ModalLogin.name, ModalLogin);
    // ...
  }
};
```

export default GlobalComponents;

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. As ModalLogin is certainly not undefined in this scope, the error can refer to another place, or the real code differs from what you posted. It's incorrect to call methods on uninstantiated component like `ModalLogin.methods.show()`.

Comment: I added my component. I don't know why it is not instantiated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The code is lacking. Try to reproduce the problem with the code you posted, you won't be able to do that. It's unknown why you expect `this.$refs['login-modal']` to exist. Again, you shouldn't call `ModalLogin.methods.show()` directly, it won't work properly. You likely have wrong idea about how to interact with components that are global to the app.